# What is the convention for dealing with scene components in Phaser 3?

Tags: phaser-framework

Say I have a game scene, CarLevelScene which is a level where I have to drive a car a certain distance. I have a "distance remaining" gauge in one corner of the scene and a "fuel remaining" gauge in another corner. In favor of single responsibility, I want to extract this from the CarLevelScene js file. In addition, on update, both of these gauges depend on some shared data (since fuel depends on distance traveled).

Right now, I essentially do something like this:

```
let fuelGuageState;
let distanceGuageState;
export default class CarLevelScene {
    init() {
        fuelGuageState = new FuelGuageState(this); // have to pass in this to create game objects in the scene. Or do I?
        distanceGuageState = new DistanceGuageState(this);
    }
    create() {
        fuelGuageState.create();
        distanceGuageState.create();
    }
    update() {
        ...
        let distance = someCalc(...); // possibly from some distance model object
        let fuel = someOtherCalc(distance, ...);
        fuelGaugeState.update(fuel);
        distanceGaugeState.update(distance);
    }
}
```

My question is, is this the conventional way to create and use components in Phaser 3? Essentially, it would make the scene an organizer of components that simply feed the correct data to each update method. It feels a bit smelly. There's temporal coupling and a lot of dependency management.

Are there official docs that deal with the appropriate organization of components in code?